# How to track customer login?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, logging

I want to track how many times customer logged in.

So as output it will be like report. From this to this day X day logged in X times.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a separate module with separate database where you need to define a observer, in which you need to write how many times a customer logged in with time & date.

```
<customer_login>
    <observers>
        <yourobservername>
            <type>model</type>
            <class>yourmodule/path_to_class</class>
            <method>customerLogin</method>
        </yourobservername>
    </observers>
</customer_login>
```

Your observer class would look like this:

```
class YourCompany_YourModule_Model_Observer
{
    public function customerLogin($observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        // ADD CURRENT SYSTEM DATE-TIME, CUSTOMER NAME, ID, ETC. IN THE DATABASE CREATED BY YOUR MODULE
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Any free or paid plugin?. because i'm newbie to magento.

Comment: Sorry, but didn't find any extension specifically for your need. Either you need to do the coding by yourself, or contact an experienced Magento developer.